# Explanation about $P(\max(X,Y)\leq1)=P(X\leq1 \cap Y\leq1)$, with $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I'm wondering why, given two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, independent and identically distributed, the following equality is correct:

$$
P(\max(X,Y)\leq1)=P(X\leq1 \cap Y\leq1)
$$

Comment: because the events are the same: $$\max(X,Y)\leq1\iff X\leq1\text{ and }Y\leq1$$ The only thing needed is that $X,Y$ are defined on the same probability space.

Comment: You don't need $X$ and $Y$ to be i.i.d. for this to hold since it actually holds for numbers: $\max(a,b) < \zeta$ if and only if $a < \zeta$ and $b < \zeta.$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @drhab and WilliamM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a comment about random variables or probability, but about numbers. For any two numbers $a, b$, the statement that $\max\{a, b\} \leq 1$ is equivalent to the statement that both $a \leq 1$ and $b \leq 1$.

(Making this a community wiki post since it contributes nothing beyond drhab's comment)